# Java: turning an arraylist into an array with an added element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I know that the code to turn an arraylist into an array is:

```
private String[] arrayLst_to_array(ArrayList<String> al) {
    String[] arr = new String[al.size()];
    arr = al.toArray(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

But I want my new array to have a certain string in the beginning and then after that, I want the rest of the arraylist.

I know that I could just add the string that I want to the beginning of the arraylist and then convert it, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Where do you have the extra strings that you want to add? Do you know how many you have before hand?

Comment: I just want to add one string.

Comment: You should aim for simplicity. Whatever makes the most sense to you now, and when you look at it in a few months from now.

Comment: if you simply have to add one string, then adding it before conversion is better. I takes **O(1)** to add to arraylist. what more efficient you looking for, to add one string?

Comment: @Zeeshan He'll have to add it to the *start* of the list, which is O(n).

Comment: Are you sure this must be "efficient"? If not, go with the easiest to read option. If it must be efficient, please explain if this refers to speed of operation or consumption of memory (or both). The easiest to read will be to insert the string prior to conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
String[] arr = new String[al.size() + 1];
arr[0] = someStr;  // initial string

// copy the list:
System.arraycopy(al.toArray(), 0, arr, 1, al.size());

return arr;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to java so I didn't think to look in the System docs. I'll accept this in 3 mins (once the timer ends)

Comment: Why do you waste so much memory? You're allocating two `String` arrays here. And you are loosing type-safety checks here because `toArray()` returns `Object[]`.

Comment: @Neet In 99.9% of cases that will be completely and utterly negligible. I dare say that even if the list is as large as possible (~2 billion) there will not be any noticeable difference. I'd rather not convolute the code by doing everything with a single array; using two is much cleared in my opinion.

Comment: @arshajii so beeing memory efficient can be neglected? Do you know how often this method has to be called? Each array pollutes the heap and causes more frequent GC which degrades overall performance.

Comment: @Neet This is undoubtedly a micro-optimization. If the OP, through extensive testing, arrives at the irrefutable conclusion that this is the source of some bottleneck, he should then think about altering this basic approach and bring into consideration the factors you detailed. Only then.

Comment: @arshajii a micro optimization? *sigh* Well, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

A memory efficient but maybe not so well performing solution would be:

```
public static String[] listPlusOne(final ArrayList<String> list, final String prepend)
{
    final String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size() + 1]);
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, list.size());
    arr[0] = prepend;
    return arr;
}
```

This solution allocates only one `String` array and performs a memory move using `System.arrayCopy()` to move all the elements one position up.

Generally speaking memory moving is always not the best solution. A `LinkedList` will allow pretty quick element prepending, but has O(n) complexity when accessing elements at random positions. The `ArrayList` is slower on prepending (memory moving, reallocation) but has O(1) when accessing elements.

So, either you use something like the code above, or you prepend the element to the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an item to the beginning of the list, the contents of the entire list have to be moved one position up. This means each element is touched twice in the entire operation. If you export the list to an array and then use `System.arrayCopy` to make room for one in the beginning, again each item is touched twice.

The easiest solution that touches each item only once seems to be creating the array, adding the string, and then iterating over the list to add its elements.

```
String[] arr = new String[al.size() + 1];
arr[0] = someStr;
int i=1;
for (String s: al) {
    arr[i++] = s;
}
```

Whether this is faster than the approaches that iterate over the items twice but benefit from the efficiency of `System.arrayCopy` should be shown by benchmarks.

Answer (score -2):

In Short Answer to your question is No.The Option you gave i believe is the best way to do it.

Comment: inserting the string in first and then converting is the fastest right?